# Call Kotlin Coroutines in parallel from suspend function in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm relatively new to coroutines, so I was wondering how can I solve my small local problem without much restructuring my Android codes.

Here is a simple setup. My ViewModel calls a `suspend` function from repository:

```
// ...ViewModel.kt

fun loadData() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val data = dataRepository.loadData()
    }
}
```

This is quite convenient, since I have a `viewModelScope` prepared for me by Android and I call a suspend function from my Repository. I don't care how the repository loads the data, I just suspend till it is returned to me.

My data repository makes several calls using `Retrofit`:

```
//...DataRepository.kt

@MainThread
suspend fun loadData(): ... {
    // Retrofit switches the contexts for me, just
    // calling `suspend fun getItems()` here.
    val items = retrofitApi.getItems()
    val itemIDs = items.map { it.id }

    // Next, getting overall list of subItems for each item. Again, each call and context
    // switch for `suspend fun retrofitApi.getSubItems(itemID)` is handled by Retrofit.
    val subItems = itemIDs.fold(mutableListOf()) { result, itemID ->
        result.apply {
            addAll(retrofitApi.getSubItems(itemID)) // <- sequential :(
        }
    }

    return Pair(items, subItems)
}
```

As you can see, since `loadData()` is a suspend function, all the calls to `retrofitApi.getSubItem(itemID)` will be executed sequentially.

However, I would like to execute them in parallel, something like `async() / await()` in coroutines would do.

I want to keep the `ViewModel` codes untouched - it should not care how the data is loaded, just launches a suspend function from own scope. I also don't want to pass any kind of scopes or other objects to my repository.

How can I do this inside a suspend function? Is the scope somehow implicitly present there? Is calling `async()` possible/allowed/good practice?

Comment: What I have understood is you want these 2 network call in loadData() to run in parallel not sequential, am I right?
But I see that you have dependant val 
val items = retrofitApi.getItems()
val itemIDs = items.map { it.id }

You are using itemIDs in :
retrofitApi.getSubItems(itemID)
So I think you should run them sequentially because of dependency. 
Please let me know if I have something missing

Comment: It will be cleaner if you use `Flow` and the `flatMapMerge` operator. Some details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58658630/parallel-request-with-retrofit-coroutines-and-suspend-functions/58659423#58659423).

Comment: Thanks @MarkoTopolnik ! I actually skipped `Flow` part when I was reading Coroutines as it seemed too much for me since I was completely new to this topic. Maybe now it is a good time to jump into it... :)

Comment: And it's a shame I didn't find that exact same question here on SO. Need to improve my googling skills.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `async` and `awaitAll` for this. You need a coroutine scope to launch new coroutines, but you can create one that inherits the existing context using `coroutineScope`.

```
suspend fun loadData(): Pair = coroutineScope {
    val items = retrofitApi.getItems()
    val itemIDs = items.map { it.id }
    val subItems = itemIDs.map { itemID ->
            async { retrofitApi.getSubItems(itemID) }
        }.awaitAll()
        .flatten()

    return@coroutineScope Pair(items, subItems)
}
```

You could have used `flatten` in your original code to simplify it a bit. (Just pointing out it's not related to decomposing these parallel tasks.) It would have looked like this:

```
val subItems = itemIDs.map { itemID ->
        retrofitApi.getSubItems(itemID)
    }.flatten()
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually not only new to coroutines, but also to Kotlin, good to learn new stuff :)

Comment: But it seems like `async` is not awailable inside my suspend function...

Comment: Sorry, see the edit. You need a scope for new coroutines, even if they're children of another one. You can easily create one using `coroutineScope`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to execute several coroutines concurrently, you'll need to use `async` launcher multiple times, then call `await` on all `Deferred` returned from `async` calls.

You can find a very similar example [here](https://github.com/techyourchance/android-multithreading-masterclass/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/techyourchance/multithreading/solutions/exercise10/ComputeFactorialUseCase.kt).

That's the most relevant part of the code:

```
private suspend fun computePartialProducts(computationRanges: Array<ComputationRange>) : List<BigInteger> = coroutineScope {
    return@coroutineScope withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        return@withContext computationRanges.map {
            computeProductForRangeAsync(it)
        }.awaitAll()
    }
}

private fun CoroutineScope.computeProductForRangeAsync(computationRange: ComputationRange) : Deferred<BigInteger> = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val rangeStart = computationRange.start
    val rangeEnd = computationRange.end

    var product = BigInteger("1")
    for (num in rangeStart..rangeEnd) {
        if (!isActive) {
            break
        }
        product = product.multiply(BigInteger(num.toString()))
    }

    return@async product
}
```