# How to fix Kotlin JobCancellationException?

Tags: android, kotlin

I got a crash because of Kotlin JobCancellationException.

The following is the detail about the crash :

```
kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: Job was cancelled; job=SupervisorJobImpl{Cancelling}@131dbe3
```

All I know is the **SupervisorJobImpl** is for ViewModelScope, and it will be called method **cancel** when ViewModel lifecycle is over.

I was so confused about the Exception because Kotlin coroutines will just ignore the Exception, but it was thrown and cause the App crash. If it has stack I can just figure out, but it doesn't, just tell me that the job was cancelled.

I spent about more than 3 days on the exception but just have no idea.

I saw the video : 
[KotlinConf 2019: Coroutines! Gotta catch 'em all! by Florina Muntenescu & Manuel Vivo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1012&v=w0kfnydnFWI&feature=emb_logo), I found if the scope is canceled, and if you call **await** on a Deferred, it will throw the Exception, but I found no **await** on the canceled scope.

So can someone just show me some code which perhaps causes the same exception and make the App crash? Thx, there.

Comment: Are you cancelling anything manually? Are you interacting with cancelled jobs or scope? It's hard to say what's the problem here.

Comment: I show all the **ViewModel#aunch** method, find nowhere call cancel manually, just ViewModel call internally.

Comment: Can you show the complete stacktrace?

Comment: no more stacktrace, that's why I post the question.

Comment: I hope someone can some code which can cause JobCancellationException thrown cause crash.

Comment: To get the full stack trace, [you need to enable coroutines debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68197547/590790).

Answer (score 15):

Finally, I found what causes the Exception and the issue address is flowing:

[kotlin.coroutines.channels.awaitClose: JobCancellationException](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1762)

Actually, `awaitClose` will not throw the `JobCancellationException`, because `awaitClose` is a cancellable suspended function. The `offer` method will throw `JobCancellationException` if the Job was canceled because `offer` is not a cancellable suspended function.

By the way, `callbackFlow` is an experimental API, so it may cause some bug, so when we use it, we need to be careful. Because it will not always ignore `JobCancellationException` when Job was canceled, and I don't think it's friendly to developers.

Now I have found 2 situations that will cause `JobCancellationException` so we need to `try catch` the exception.

1. `async await`, when we call the `await` method we need to `try catch`. And you can find and example in the [Video](https://youtu.be/w0kfnydnFWI).
2. `callbackFlow offer`, when we call the `offer` method we need to `try catch`. And you can find an example in the issue above.

Comment: Hi, similar thing is happening with me. I wrapped my job = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { } inside try-catch. Still exception not going in catch block. How did you fix the issue?

Comment: You should not wrap `launch` inside a try-catch, you need to try-catch the code inside `launch`.

Comment: @Shrikant You need to find which code causes the exception and wrap it with try-catch.

Comment: Take a look at this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58734114/how-to-spot-where-job-was-cancelled-exception-comes-from-when-all-your-corouti

Answer (score 8):

I know I am late but you can just check Job Status before offering objects.
Like this

```
if(isActive) offer(Resource.success(response))
```

**isActive** is Coroutine Scope

Comment: Yep, thanks. try catch is not the best way, this one is better.

Comment: Yep. This makes the most sense. If the job is no longer active just don't call offer.

Answer (score 4):

I just saw the same problem. The issue was caused by the activity being finished manually before the job managed to complete.

Comment: how do you find otu what job still needs completing?

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the issue was caused due to an inner part of the code using non-reactive code which was causing the upper-level dispatched coroutines to be canceled. At the end of the day, I fixed the problem by using the necessary reactive code in the underlying layer but, I was able to catch it by switching from:

```
withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
    // dispatched coroutine
}
```

to:

```
withContext(NonCancellable) {
    // dispatched coroutine
}
```

This stopped "hiding" the problem and pointed me right to the root of the of it.

Hope this helps =)

Comment: very helpful and straightforward solution

Answer (score 1):

1. I closed a `ViewModel` and a dialog and then started a `Job`. It led to this exception and HTTP-request cancellation: [HTTP FAILED: java.io.IOException: Canceled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40823134/retrofit-api-call-receives-http-failed-java-io-ioexception-canceled/).

   ```
   close()
   modelScope.launch {
       val response = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
           ...
       }
       response?.let { ... }
   }
   ```

I simply moved `close()` to the end.

2. When you call one coroutine from another, parent coroutine will cancel nested, if finish quicker. For instance:

   ```
   viewModelScope.launch {
       // Launch a request.
       ...
       // Now launch a nested coroutine.
       viewModelScope.launch { // (1)
           ... // Can be cancelled. (2)
       }
   }
   ```

   You can remove `viewModelScope.launch {` in (1) and rewrite a nested block as `suspended`. If you want a parallel work, use [async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60836667/call-kotlin-coroutines-in-parallel-from-suspend-function-in-android) or this:

   ```
   viewModelScope.launch {
       ...
   }
   // A parallel coroutine.
   viewModelScope.launch {
       ...
   }
   ```
3. There is a case when everything works well, but once in 100 clicks a coroutine cancels itself (the same "HTTP FAILED: java.io.IOException: Canceled"). Nothing helped, until I changed `lifecycleScope.launch` to `lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same bug as you. So I try to write simple flow extensions like below:

```
fun <P> Flow<DataResult<P>>.safeStart(start: suspend FlowCollector<DataResult<P>>.() -> Unit)
        : Flow<DataResult<P>> =  onStart {
        if (!currentCoroutineContext().isActive) return@onStart
        start()
    }

fun <P> Flow<DataResult<P>>.safeCatch(onCatch: suspend FlowCollector<DataResult<P>>.(cause: Throwable) -> Unit)
        : Flow<DataResult<P>> = catch {
        if (!currentCoroutineContext().isActive) return@catch
        onCatch(it)
}

suspend inline fun <P> Flow<DataResult<P>>.safeCollect(crossinline onCollect: suspend (value: DataResult<P>) -> Unit)
        : Unit = collect {
    if (!currentCoroutineContext().isActive) return@collect
    onCollect(it)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same crash when I used `callbackFlow` with `offer` with coroutines version `1.3.5`.
Now instead of offer I use `trySend` and it's fixed.

Note:
`trySend` method is available (and `offer` is deprecated) when you update coroutines version to:

```
org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.0
```