# How to enable coroutine debug mode when running an Android App from Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-coroutines

I'm getting a coroutine exception while running my Android app in debug mode through Android Studio.

> kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: StandaloneCoroutine was cancelled

From the [coroutines debugging documentation](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/docs/topics/debugging.md#debug-mode), I gather that I might get fuller stack trace information by enabling *debug mode* of coroutines.

> It can be enabled either by setting system property DEBUG_PROPERTY_NAME or by running Java with enabled assertions (-ea flag).

This is where I'm stuck. What is the idiomatic way of achieving this in Android Studio? My project is configured using Gradle, and I am running on Windows. Ideally, there is a way to configure this through Gradle configuration so that coroutines debug mode is enabled for anyone pulling in this project through source control.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't found a way to configure this through Android studio or Gradle. Information on doing so would still be useful to me. But, the following is verified to work; I got a full stack trace.

The "system property" refers to [Java System Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html). They can be set at runtime using `System.setProperty`.

I therefore added the following code to the start of my `Application.onCreate()`.

```
override fun onCreate() {
    // Enable coroutines debug mode in debug builds.
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        System.setProperty(
            kotlinx.coroutines.DEBUG_PROPERTY_NAME,
            kotlinx.coroutines.DEBUG_PROPERTY_VALUE_ON
        )
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: You'd preferably run this in a static initializer block, to execute before ContentProviders and androidx.startup.Initializers.

Answer (score 2):

Coroutine debugging is not (currently) supported in Android Studio.

It was briefly added in 2021 but then removed due to performance problems. Here's [the tracking bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-335195).

There's also some additional information from the kotlinx-coroutines-debug project:

> Android runtime does not support Instrument API necessary for kotlinx-coroutines-debug to function, triggering java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;, and it is not possible to use coroutine debugger along with Android emulator.

Source: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/kotlinx-coroutines-debug#debug-agent-and-android